# Window 7 using command line and dir: missing folder

Tags: windows, command-line, dir

I copied a folder *sfold1* into folder *fold* and wanted to access *sfold1* with console cmd. When I go to folder *fold* and ask for listing the subfolders *sfold1* is missing:

```
c:\fold>dir
.
..
sfold2
sfold3
```

I can see *sfold1* with windows-explorer and also I can open it:

```
c:\fold>cd sfold1
c:\fold\sfold1>
```

It seems like that I have to do a refresh. How can I cope with this?

Comment: Explorer needs refreshing - the cmd prompt is dynamic.  Without a screenshot any advice is a guess, but try `dir /a`

Comment: Thanks. I will try that a soon I'm back from holidays.